# search lucene NumericField for maximum value

Tags: lucene

I know there is a NumericRangeQuery in Lucene but is it possible to have lucene simply return the maximum value stored in in a NumericField.  I can use a RangeQuery over the entire known range and then sort but this is extremely cumbersome and it may return a huge amount of results if there are a lot of records

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `IndexSearcher.search(Query query, int n, Sort sort)` allows to specify the top n hits (in your case 1), which, if you sort correctly, only returns the desired result. There are other overloaded methods that allow achieving the same.

Can't argue about the cumbersomeness though :)

Answer (score 0):

You could [Term Enum](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TermEnum.html) through your index. Unfortunately I don't think they're sorted in a way which makes finding the maximum instantaneous, but at least you won't have to do an actual search to find it. You will need to use [NumericUtils](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/util/NumericUtils.html) to convert from Lucene's internal structure to a normal number.

[This thread](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Numeric-field-min-max-values-td3474881.html) contains an example.